# Installing 'fabric-customise-controls' in angular app

Tags: angular, fabricjs, yarnpkg

I have an angular app that uses fabric library. I need to customise the controls of objects so I tried to install fabric-customise-controls package. I wrote:

```
yarn add 'fabric-customise-controls'
```

But when I try to use its extension methods I get error:

```
Property 'customiseCornerIcons' does not exist on type 'Object'
```

Do I have to install anything else for it to work?

Comment: You should look at fabricJS 4 beta. I think it has all the necessary code changes to embed the functionality of the control customization

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Are there any more docs for the controls interface than this page http://fabricjs.com/custom-control-render ? I want to move the controls to be inside bounding box and I have no idea how to achieve that

Comment: Not yet, i have to write it but i m not free this period. That page show how to build a control that has an icon instead of the standard one, and how to attach a custom function to it. Depending on what feature of 'fabric-customise-controls' you are after you may need more examples. You could open an issue of the type help request on the fabricjs tracker, not for your yarn/library problem but to explain which features of the custom control libraries you are looking to and if they are covered.